# Parsing data from serial port thread-safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I read data from the serial port and parse it in a separate class. However data is incorrectly parsed and some samples are repeated while others are missing.

Here is an example of the parsed packet. It starts with the packetIndex (shoudl start from 1 and incrementing). You can see how the packetIdx repeats and some of the other values repeat as well. I think that's due to multithreading but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
    2 -124558.985180734 -67934.4168823262 -164223.049786454 -163322.386243628
    2 -124619.580759952 -67962.535376851 -164191.757344217 -163305.68949052
    3 -124685.719571795 -67995.8394760894 -164191.042088394 -163303.119039907 
    5 -124801.747477263 -68045.7062179692 -164195.288919841 -163299.140429394 
    6 -124801.747477263 -68045.7062179692 -164221.105184687 -163297.46404856 
    6 -124832.8387538 -68041.9287731563 -164214.936103217 -163294.983004926
```

This is what I should receive:

```
1 -124558.985180734 -67934.4168823262 -164223.049786454 -163322.386243628
2 -124619.580759952 -67962.535376851 -164191.757344217 -163305.68949052
3 -124685.719571795 -67995.8394760894 -164191.042088394 -163303.119039907 
4 -124801.747477263 -68045.7062179692 -164195.288919841 -163299.140429394 
 ...
```

This is the SerialPort_DataReceived

```
 public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[_serialPort1.BytesToRead];
            _serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                //Parse data
                double[] samplesAtTimeT = DataParserObj.interpretBinaryStream(buffer[i]);
                //Add data to BlockingCollection when parsed 
                if (samplesAtTimeT != null)
                    _bqBufferTimerSeriesData.Add(samplesAtTimeT);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the class that parses the data:

```
public class DataParser
{
    private int packetSampleCounter = 0;
    private int localByteCounter = 0;
    private int packetState = 0;
    private byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[3];
    private double[] ParsedData = new double[5]; //[0] packetIdx (0-255), [1-4] signal


    public double[] interpretBinaryStream(byte actbyte)
    {
        bool returnDataFlag = false;

        switch (packetState)
        {
            case 0: // end packet indicator
                if (actbyte == 0xC0)
                    packetState++;
                break;
            case 1: // start packet indicator
                if (actbyte == 0xA0)
                    packetState++;
                else
                    packetState = 0;
                break;
            case 2: // packet Index 
                packetSampleCounter = 0;
                ParsedData[packetSampleCounter] = actbyte;
                packetSampleCounter++;
                localByteCounter = 0;
                packetState++;
                break;
            case 3: //channel data (4 channels x 3byte/channel)
                // 3 bytes
                tmpBuffer[localByteCounter] = actbyte;
                localByteCounter++;
                if (localByteCounter == 3)
                {
                    ParsedData[packetSampleCounter] = Bit24ToInt32(tmpBuffer);
                    if (packetSampleCounter == 5)
                        packetState++; //move to next state, end of packet
                    else
                        localByteCounter = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 4: // end packet
                if (actbyte == 0xC0)
                {
                    returnDataFlag = true;
                    packetState = 1;
                }
                else
                    packetState = 0;
                break;
            default:
                packetState = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (returnDataFlag)
            return ParsedData;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (actbyte == 0xA0) {packetState++}, but the initial value is zero? So next time, you are hitting case 1 again? Is this even correct? I think the DataParser is a great example of a class which needs unit tests!

Comment: @Odrai True, packetState should be 1 on init. This only affects the first iteration, for the rest of iterations packetState should be already 1 when is in case 1.

Comment: if (actbyte = 0xC0), one missing equal sign? Please update your post and use curly brackets.

Comment: Yes, it was correct in my code. The packetState returning to 0 is to instead of 1 is to resync.

Comment: @nabrugir Please add (all missing) curly brackets to the code sample, so it is easier to follow the flow of the 'interpretBinaryStream' method. (e.g. if (localByteCounter == 3) doesn't have an ending bracket).

Comment: @Odrai Done. The tests I did with breakpoints work fine. It seems to me the issue is when different threads access. If I remove the lock() in the DataReceived, I get several lines equal, meaning it returns the same ParsedData[].

Comment: Did you only  subscribed (+=) once to the serialPort1_DataReceived? If so, why using a lock? The BlockingCollection is already thread-safe. As already mentioned by @Alexei Levenkov, could you add the multithreading parts in the OP?

Comment: @Odrai I think the issue is that it was suscribing twice to the serialPort, thats why without a lock was giving me problems. Is that possible?

Comment: @nabrugir Subscribing twice could indeed be the issue and causing issues when using the same 'DataParserObj' object.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: `DataReceived` is called on a worker thread, so this question absolutely involves multithreading.  Please check that you know what you are talking about before presuming to tell OP how to improve his question.

Comment: @Odrai: The serial port doesn't wait for the `DataReceived` event handler to finish, if after `serialPort.Read()` more data arrives, the `DataReceived` event will fire again in another worker thread.

Comment: @BenVoigt Does the serial port have its own thread? Or uit uses any worker thread? I found both answers online. It's crucial to know if when new data is received, it will wait or fire again.

Comment: @nabrugir: The `SerialPort` class uses worker threads from the thread pool, but you don't have to interact with them if you don't use the events.  `async`/`await` is more convenient for event-driven processing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `DataReceived` event and instead use `await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(....)` to get notified when data comes in.  `async`/`await` is much cleaner and doesn't force you into multithreaded data processing.  For high speed networking, parallel processing is great.  But serial ports are slow, so extra threads have no benefit.

Also, `BytesToRead` is buggy (it does return the number of queued bytes, but it destroys other state) and you should never call it.

Finally, do NOT ignore the return value from `Read` (or `BaseStream.ReadAsync`).  You need to know how bytes were actually placed into your buffer, because it is not guaranteed to be the same number you asked for.

```
private async void ReadTheSerialData()
{
     var buffer = new byte[200];
     while (serialPort.IsOpen) {
         var valid = await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         for (int i = 0; i < valid; ++i)
         {
             //Parse data
            double[] samplesAtTimeT = DataParserObj.interpretBinaryStream(buffer[i]);
            //Add data to BlockingCollection when parsed 
            if (samplesAtTimeT != null)
                _bqBufferTimerSeriesData.Add(samplesAtTimeT);
         }
     }
}
```

Just call this function after opening the port and setting your flow control, timeouts, etc.  You may find that you no longer need the blocking queue, but can just handle the contents of `samplesAtTimeT` directly.

Comment: Do you have some example? I find tons for DataReceived but not a lot for RedSync. Is this a good one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e86ecd5d-ea45-4726-9f53-6e4af007fa05/readasync-from-serialport-with-basestream?forum=csharpgeneral?

Comment: @nabrugir: No, that one's horrible.  I'll add the skeleton for how ReadAsync should work.

Comment: It works but when Im plotting the received data it doesnt seem its continuosly receiving data (it did with the DataReceived). I decreased buffer size to byte[10].  and I'm plotting the data by reading the bqBufferTimeSeriesData every 20ms and plotting all the samples available. The device is sampling every 4ms.

Comment: Did you try just doing the plot immediately after the "Parse Data" step?  What's your baud rate?  For a sample group every 4ms, you'll need 15*250*10 = 37500 baud or higher (which is not hard to achieve).  Note that you can also call `ReadAsync` and save the `Task<int>` it returns, then do some plotting, then `await` the task and do the parsing, then repeat.

Comment: BTW a buffer size of 10 is pointless, since each of your messages is 15 bytes.  You also mention wanting to collect 20ms of data at a time, which is 4 messages.  Therefore, a buffer size of 60 or so would be recommended.

Comment: Baudrate is 115200, it's what was recommended for the device. After the ParseData I read the blockingqueue and I filter the data. I have then a timer that every 20ms plots any data available after the filtering.